# Running a Ruby Script from Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, execute

I have a very basic website where a user inputs text to a text field form and submits this text. The text then is supposed to be a parameter for a Ruby script, which will in turn return data based on this supplied text.

My questions:

1. Can you execute a Ruby script from a Controller?
2. If yes, what if this Ruby script takes a few minutes until it returns data? Delayed job?
3. Instead of running a Ruby script, can I import the function from this Ruby script into my controller?

I am still a novice to Rails so I thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. delayed_job (or its alternatives) is a good idea. 3. Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you execute a Ruby script from a Controller?

Yes you can, fa the scripts is external, like:

```
system('script.rb')
```

But of course the better way is to embed the script into the `Rails` app.

> If yes, what if this Ruby script takes a few minutes until it returns data? Delayed job?

Of course Delayed Job, see [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) on how to do that.

> Instead of running a Ruby script, can I import the function from this Ruby script into my controller?

Of course yes, and that way is preferrable, but anyway if that is available to implement.